# Carmichael number satisfying three conditions

Tags: number-theory

Is there a composite number $n$ that satisfies these conditions?

1. $2^{1023}  \le  n  <  2^{1024}$, i.e. $n$ is a $1024$-bit number
2. $n$ is not divisible by the first $100,000$ primes.
   i.e.  $n$ is not divisible by:   $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, ..., 1299673, 1299689, 1299709$.
3. $2^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Thanks,
-Sreekanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of the form $(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$ is a carmichael number, if $6k+1,12k+1,18k+1$ are primes.

For example, you can choose $$k=517650756218845366184212315943571036707896549095850$$ $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 962251360894402402388429301076756049205096941045206$$

a $102$ digit-number.

Comment: $N:=(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)$ then satisfies all your conditions.

Comment: Thanks. What if we add an extra condition: n must not have a factor close to 6*cube-root(n/1296)  (say, plus or minus 1000)?

Comment: In general, if I use this simple algorithm to create a random 1024-bit prime, what is the probability that I make a mistake?

Comment: Let me clarify:  The algorithm creates a random 1024-bit number, and it passes all the above tests:   No small prime factor, Fermat test says it is ok, and there is no factor close to 6*cube-root(n/1296).   What is the probability that n is composite?

Comment: As I mentioned, it is enough that $(6k+1),(12k+1)$ and $(18k+1)$ are all prime-

Comment: For a random number, near $0$. And the last condition is not necessary.

Comment: If you have a random number (not being of my special form), and the number passes one Fermat-test (Weak test is sufficient), the probability it is composite, is also very, very small. To get more informations, you can visit Chris Caldwell's prime page. Search the site Probable prime-How probable ?

Comment: An ARBITARY number that passes the STRONG-probable-prime test for $n$ distinct random bases, is prime with a probability of at least $1-\frac{1}{4}^n$.

Comment: The strong-probable-prime test is explained in wikipedia - miller rabin test.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Finally, the adle-pomerance-rumely test (APR) proves a number to be prime and is very fast for numbers with upto $200$ digits. My example consists of proven primes.